# explicit integral in Poincare formula

Tags: calculus

I am trying to see an explicit integral, which proves Poincaré's Lemma in several variables in $R^n$. Given a smooth local $k$- form $\phi$, then this is exact i.e
there is $k-1$-form $\alpha$ such that $d\alpha =\phi$.

Is it possible to give an expression of $\alpha $ as integral involving $\phi$?

Thanks.

Comment: yes it is, given an explicit formula for $\phi$ you can write such a formula. It is just the coordinate expression for the abstract formulas written in terms of pull-backs etc...

Comment: I have expanded a proof from Flander's differential form text (available as Dover) in my 2011 advanced calculus notes. If you look at section 9.6 of http://www.supermath.info/AdvancedCalculus2011.pdf then you'll see how the Poincare lemma explicitly reproduces potentials for conservative vector fields. Flanders has the derivation of a vector potential for the magnetic field also from Poincare's lemma. I think maybe what you ask is  equivalent to proving the generalized stokes theorem. So, a glib answer is just use the FTC, but the exterior algebra and construction of the...

Comment: integrals of differential forms is a large part of what makes this all work. You could recast it as an integral in $n$-dimensions, but that robs it of the true structure which is explicit in form/wedge notation. But, maybe I misunderstand your question.